# The URL bitbucket provides is invalid in SourceTree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

**The URL Bitbucket provides is invalid in SourceTree**

When I try to clone a repository to my local machine the URL Bitbucket provides is just wrong. The site provides me with a URL like this:
*https://pelletierscott@bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo.git*

I can manually get the correct URL from the browser which is like this:
*https://bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo/src/master/*

Bitbucket has a dedicated service to add repo's to SourceTree but it has the same issue. Am I missing something, I'm I not understanding the process?

EDIT: The two URL's given are for example and do not link to an actual repository.

Comment: What do you mean that "the URL Bitbucket provides is just wrong"? I assume you mean the "https://pelletierscott@bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo.git" URL? Why is it wrong? Where do you use this URL and what happens when you do? What actual error do you get? And how do you know that "https://bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo/src/master/" is correct? I think the wording "wrong" and "correct" is too vague here. Both of these URLs are completely valid. Whether or not they "work" depends on what you are trying to do with them.

Comment: "The two URL's given are for example and do not link to an actual repository." if you don't give real data you can't get real help.

Comment: "pelletierscott@bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo.git" is wrong because it fails to validate in SourceTree, VS Code, or through GIT CLI.

Answer (score 4):

> I can manually get the correct URL from the browser which is like this: https://bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo/src/master/

This is not the correct URL to use with Sourcetree or git. Instead, click on the Clone button at the top right of your repository's main page and copy *that* URL.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to clone a repository to my local machine the URL Bitbucket provides is just wrong.

No, **you** are wrong: default URL for your repository on BB `https://bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/portfolio.git` is perfectly valid and correct, while `https://bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo/src/master/`is just *one of possible* web-views of repo

> Bitbucket has a dedicated service to add repo's to SourceTree but it has the same issue

Wrong again:

1. It's not BB-service, just specially crafted URL with own protocol and parameters
2. SourceTree's URL `sourcetree://cloneRepo?cloneUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org%2Fpelletierscott%2Fportfolio.git&type=bitbucket`, as all and any other known and unknows protocols, have to be processed by *your local OS*, which have to know how to do it after *full and proper installation* of SourceTree

Anyway, you can **always** use [Method 1](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/clone-a-repository-into-sourcetree-780870050.html) from Atlassian's docs

Comment: I don't know what so tell you. 

https://pelletierscott@bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo.git

Should redirect to

https://bitbucket.org/pelletierscott/repo/src/master/

But none of the git services I use including CLI will validate the bitbucket URL given to clone the repo.